# Julia - How to handle broadcast dot notation with AbstractRGB type?

Tags: colors, julia

i'm new to julia and i dont understand how to handle the AbstractRGB type.
i want to write a function that inverts a color.

this is my code:

```
function invert(color::AbstractRGB)
    return(RGB(1-color.r,1-color.g,1-color.b))
end
```

but i want to use the dot broadcast notation. this was my attempt:

```
function invert(color::AbstractRGB)
    return (1 .- color)
end
```

it gives me this error

```
MethodError: no method matching -(::Int64, ::ColorTypes.RGB{Float64})
```

packages used:

```
using Images
```

and an example of using the function:

```
invert(RGB(0.0,0.0,0.0))
```

Comment: To make your example code runnable, can you add the required `using` statements (in other words, which packages are you using?), and the input that you provide to the `invert` function?

Comment: @CameronBieganek added it to the post

Comment: It's probably worth noting that due to complicated color theory inverting a color isn't an especially well defined operation. For example does inversion take into account gamma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I'm not suggesting you actually do this, but...

```
julia> invert(c::AbstractRGB) = RGB((1 .- getproperty.(c, (:r, :g, :b)))...)
invert (generic function with 1 method)

julia> invert(RGB(.3, .5, .8))
RGB{Float64}(0.7,0.5,0.19999999999999996)
```

Comment: oh thanks. but is there a reason that 1 - .8 returns .19999999999999996 in this case?

Comment: floating point error

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, I would argue. You can't subtract a real number from a colour since those two things live in different "domains" (universe, if you will). And it's not clear "broadcasting" through different channels of color makes sense, since those are 3 components of the same "pixel", not some physics axis.

---

Since you don't own `Base.:-`, the type `Int`, not the type `RGB`, you also shouldn't specialise in this function yourself; doing so commits the "crime" of type piracy.